# what is simple MVC based PHP blogging application?

Tags: model-view-controller, blogs

I am searching for a Blogging tools like wordpress. But I want MVC based tools to extend my blog with MVC structure.

My main requirements is

1. Must be based on MVC
2. Simple & lightweight
3. it's blog url structure should be domain.com/cat_name/post_title , because my current wordpress blog is like that, I don't want to lose Facebook Share and Tweets.

I want a simple one, because this is learning only.

Answer (score 2):

Clarifying: if a CMS you use is based on a MVC design pattern or not is irrelevant to you as an user, except if you want to meddle with its inner workings (which you don't - a CMS is made to be used and possibly extended, but in 99% of use cases, if it isn't extendable to your needs, changing the source code is a bad idea, as it will most likely break with any updates you may want to make)

You may want a MVC framework, which will in turn allow you to **code** a CMS of your own, or use a good, extendable, CMS app

The one I use is [ProcessWire](http://www.processwire.com), which is a CMS/CMF (F stands for Framework) php app, and seems to be the kind of thing you are looking for - it manages your content for you (the default installation comes with a few demo pages) but you define the fields, and you use them to display your content at will. Check it out - the user forum is quite active, and people there are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are tons of Content Managment System Based on MVC frameworks (eg . CodeIgniter ) .  I personally recommend Pyro ( Based on CodeIgniter) but other also seem promising . but i don't know much since i haven't tried .

Comment: But Pyro is CMS. Is there any blogging tools?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a highly relative question and will bring forth a ton of opinions and not real answers. With that in mind, here is my answer.

I know of a tool that you can use to install an MVC template for and on top of ProcessWire along with basic project managing tasks using gulp. Note, the M will be considered ProcessWire.

Have a look on github.com and look at the profile of fixate and repo generator-fixate-pw. (ie: [generator-fixate-pw](http://github.com/fixate/generator-fixate-pw), added the sentence if the link breaks).

Install this by following the instructions on the repository. The tool is very specific but learning to use the framework helped improve my php skills allot (still learning allot).

Whether the CMS will be used as a blog or not will depend on your implementation of the install.